# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error in SSIS package

Tags: c#, ssis

I have the following code in a script task but when I try execute the script I get an error with the following message: "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I am trying to address a deadlock error in my package with the use of variables. Based on the value of Region, I'm trying to populate another variable InputRegion.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        String InputFile;
        int StrLen;
        Variables var = null;    
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::Region", ref var);
        var[0].Value = "DEFAULT";
        InputFile = (String)vars["User::InputRegion"].Value;

        if (InputFile == "Europe.txt")
            var[0].Value = "European";
        if (InputFile == "Amers.txt")
            var[0].Value = "American";
        if (InputFile == "Tokyo.txt")
            var[0].Value = "Asian";
        else        
            var[0].Value = "Unknown";

        var.Unlock();

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that exception ?

Comment: Hard to tell without the full code. You could `assume` that `var` is null and has not been initalised in your `LockOneForWrite` method.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: I would advise against using a variable name that's the same as a key word. var is a keyword in C#.  Variable names should be descriptive.  Not identifying that as the problem just making a general statement.

Answer (score 2):

With the given informations, I can guess that :

### The problem

```
 Variables var = null;
```

You initialize your variable with a `null` valu and then you use it without giving a value.
Because you use it there (probably where you get the exception too)

```
  Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::Region", ref var);
```

### Also

If the line of code above doesn't set a value to var, your program could crash :

- There:    `var[0].Value = "DEFAULT";`
- There:    `var[0].Value = "European";`
- There:    `var[0].Value = "American";`
- There:    `var[0].Value = "Asian";`
- There:    `var[0].Value = "Unknown";`
- Or There: `var.Unlock();`

### Possible Solution

Try giving it a valid value instead of `null` to make sure the problem is there.